Difference Data Collected and Reference Sinus
I have a signal generator with 40 MHz bandwidth and 1.2 GSa/s features. I generate a 9.7 MHz sine on this generator. I sample using ADC demo board at 100 MHz. I generate a reference signal in MATLAB and plot it.
I find the phase difference between the two signals (collect and reference) and add them and plot them on top of each other.
Fs = 100e6;
T = 1/Fs;
L = length(collect_data);
p_end = (L-1)*T;
t = 0:1/Fs:p_end;
reference_sin = max(collect_data)*sin(2*pi*9.7e6*t+phase_diff);

An image taken from the middle of this data can also be seen when looking at the sample number. There are errors but they are less and the phase is correct. The blue signal is the signal collected by the ADC, and the orange signal is the signal drawn as a reference.

In the beginning of the data, we see that there is a phase difference between the data and the reference and the error increases significantly.

When we look at the last parts of the data, we observe that there are many errors and phase difference.

When I plot the error difference between the summed and the reference, it looks like the figure.
plot(collect_data-reference_sin)


We understand that the phase is correct at the midpoints by the decrease in the error. However, as we get to the beginning and end parts, the error increases up to 2000 LSBs. Because of the phase difference.
I'm trying to understand why. Even if there is both gain and offset error, the error code is too much. How can I fix this?
Edit : It was stated which signal was which color.

Can you explain what is what in the graph and where exactly the discrepancy is? It would also help if you could zoom in to just a few periods in the "good" area and the "bad " area. And it's always a good idea to label your axes. What units are you using?

also, this is a Matlab plot. Please don't take photos of a computer screen with a camera. your Matlab plot has a "save figure" (as PNG) functionality. Then we get the full picture, you have less work cropping things out). Also, please edit your question to add your matlab code – I suspect it's not very much that you needed to generate a sine wave – showing how you generate the reference signal and the difference graph. Please remove as much guessing from what we need to help you!

the generator may have a slight frequency drift meaning you say 9.7MHz it produces 9.7MHz but not all the time the actual frequency oscillating from 9.69999 .. 9.70001 MHz.

Try collecting more samples, 10 times what you did, and try to find out if it's a cycle, meaning if both signals show good match and mismatch following a cycle.

The OP is likely seeing a small frequency offset error between the captured and reference signal. The fix is to adjust the frequency (and phase) error between the reference and the signal.
The offset in frequency could be happening if the 100 MHz sampling clock and the signal generator creating the test signal are not locked to a common reference. This would mean that the 100 MHz sampling clock when compared to the master clock within the signal generator has a small frequency offset, which is inevitable with free-running systems. One solution is to phase lock the two systems if possible (generate the 100 MHz sampling clock from another signal generator and have both locked to a common 10 MHz reference). Phase locking the two systems is not always feasible, and it is more realistic to include the possibility of such frequency offsets in general.
The offset in frequency is consistent with the OP's zoomed in plots showing the phase gradually moving between the two as we transition in time from the start and end of the sequence: my guess from the plots is the phase error of reference-ADC is approximately +0.25 radians at the start of the sequence to -0.25 radians at the end of the sequence (I estimated that using small angle approximations by dividing the peak error envelope of 2000 by the peak signal magnitude of 8000 and from the zoomed in plots we see that the reference is leading the ADC). The total length is approximately 50,000 samples, so at 100 MSps this would correspond to a 500 us total time duration. Frequency is the time derivative of phase (a change of phase vs a change in time)  and therefore we can estimate the frequency error to approximately be $-0.5$ radians divided by $500$ us  = $-1000$ radians/sec or $-1000/(2\pi) = -159$ Hz. This would be the error in the 9.7 MHz value used.
The OP has thus implemented a crude phase measurement by using the difference between the two signals in that the resulting envelope of the error signal (what we see in the OP's final plot) will have a magnitude that is proportional to the magnitude of the phase, consistent with small angle approximations. I say "crude" because it provides a simple metric sufficient for immediate use, while noting better phase measurement approaches exist if more accurate or closed loop automated solutions are needed. From the error envelope, we don't know the sign of the phase error but we are able to determined that from the zoomed in plots at the start and end. (I would however recommend as a simple update that the amplitudes of the two waveforms be matched using the rms value for each waveform rather than the single maximum value as currently done; matching amplitude using correlation would be optimum but rms is simple as the starting value for this higher SNR condition.)
Specific Recommendation on what to do:
The OP could easily minimize the error observed by manually adjusting the reference signal while observing the error signal as follows: Start with my initial guess of 9.7MHz + 159 Hz and see if the resulting slope of the error envelope reduces (there will still be large error overall, we are just looking at the envelope of it at this point to remove frequency error). If not, I made a sign error and try 9.7 MHz - 159 Hz. Either way keep iterating with smaller steps in the direction toward less slope to make the envelope as flat as possible (this would correspond to zero frequency error). After that is determined, adjust the phase offset (“phase_diff” in the formula used to create the reference signal) iteratively to reduce the peak to peak magnitude in the error envelope (resulting in zero phase error on average) Using the zoomed in plot as the phase is adjusted would likely be helpful.
(Side note that we could similarly instead adjust the value used for 'Fs' in the code by increasing it by the same proportion: -159/9.7e6 or +16 ppm, while holding the frequency value at 9.7 MHz; the end result would be the same).
Confirming my suspicions I did a quick check to see what would match the OP's result. The following was generated by subtracting two tones sampled at 100 MHz, each 49050 samples in length, with one as the "ADC" at 9.7 MHz + 159 Hz and the other as the "reference" with a frequency of exactly 9.7 MHz. I adjusted the phase offset to be 0.245 radians and amplitude offset to be 190 codes with the goal of matching the OP's plot. Needlessly but for the DSP sport of it I even added some noise and rounded the result to be fixed-point (Python code used listed below):
import numpy as np
fs = 100e6
nsamps = 49050
t = np.arange(nsamps)/fs
amp = 8000
f_ref = 9.7e6
f_error = 159
amp_error = 190
phase_diff = 0.245
noise = 15*np.random.randn(nsamps)
adc = np.round(-amp * np.cos(2 * np.pi * (f_ref + f_error) * t) + noise)
reference = np.round(-(amp + amp_error) * np.cos(2 * np.pi * f_ref * t + phase_diff))


Zooming in on the start of the plot showing the phase relationship is similar to the OP's zoomed plot:

The approach of using the difference signal that the OP has already created to resolve the frequency error would be sufficient to confirm the issue and understand how it can be resolved. For more accurate measurement of frequency and phase error, appropriate for a more automated and direct solution, I recommend using the Hilbert Transform to get the analytic signal (positive frequency component only) and with that the instantaneous phase versus time of the sampled signal can be more accurately and directly measured. From that the frequency can be measured as well since instantaneous frequency is the time derivative of phase. The analytic signal is the complex result directly returned by the ‘Hilbert’ function in Matlab, Octave and scipy.signal- so this would not be very complicated to do especially for such a narrow band tone. Another approach for small angles as was experienced here is to just multiply the normalized ADC signal and reference and then low pass filter the result. The product will be proportional to the cosine of the phase error, from which phase and frequency can be estimated and reduced to zero error iteratively or in a loop.
I demonstrate the approach of using the Hilbert method in Python below (the first and last 100 samples are removed due to the edge effects of the Hilbert function used), with the result being an accurate measurement of phase versus time, from which we can determine in one pass the phase and frequency offset (frequency as the slope of phase versus time):
adc_a = sig.hilbert(adc)
ref_a = sig.hilbert(reference)
phase = -np.unwrap(np.angle(adc_a * np.conj(ref_a)))
freq = fs * np.diff(phase) / (2 * np.pi)
print(f"The estimated frequency error is {np.mean(freq[100:-100]):0.2f} Hz")
plt.figure(figsize=(5,3))
plt.plot(t[100:-100], phase[100:-100])



Thanks very much for the answer. Some points are confusing to me. I'm new to this, sorry. I don't understand what OP's definition means. How did you understand the 0.25 radians info? Can you please explain the connection of 0.4? Should 19MHz actually be the stopband frequency of the filter? Are you suggesting build a close loop structure for phase_diff that check the error every time?  I was basically trying to get to the ref. signal with a multiplication and sum coefficient. Is this possible? I search how to apply Hilbert transform to this signal. What exactly do we expect the impact to be?

I apologize for the confusion, that was my fault in rushing the answer not yours for being new to it. OP means “Original Poster”. (See meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385612/6415629).  I rewrote it to be clearer and added examples simulating what I thought your waveform was.  Hope this helps and good luck!

Your answer is really very descriptive, you created the first two graphs in the same way, thank you. My reply is late because I'm really trying to understand. I understand that there is an offset in frequency up to 159 Hz and it affects it positively and negatively. But I'm having a hard to understand what impact Hilbert has here. I want to confirm whether I got it right or not. Hilbert can complex a real signal and be used to find its phase.

What do you mean here is to operate with a phase angle that changes in each sample, rather than a constant phase angle? Otherwise, when I add the estimated frequency error, I will see shifts in the middle and end parts of the signal. Could you explain in more detail the Hilbert part?

I think you can completely resolve your issue without Hilbert, and recommend doing that first (using the simple approach I first described)- success with that will help provide a further understanding as to what is occurring and why. Understanding the Hilbert is a bit more advanced and more than I can fully describe here beyond the bottom line approach I gave. I do teach online classes that do go through all this in detail very intuitively with the proper background-- if you're interested and have the time / energy to really learn it, the "DSP for Wireless Comm" class is happening right now:

you can find info here and still sign up (all sessions are recorded for later viewing through the end of Sept): https://dsprelated.com/courses. It's the "DSP for Wireless Comm" class specifically that details the Hilbert and other topics useful for what you are doing here.

The first way really solved my problem. The difference is less than 200 LSB and the frequency in phased.

Great to hear, thanks for letting me know. Also try adjusting the gain balance too to see if it reduces the 200 LSB further-- ultimately you will be left with your noise. Glad it worked. The Hilbert approach is good if you are then going to be doing this a lot and need dynamic automated adjustments. For a one shot test then what you did as you did would be just fine.
